# Are there immutable STL container classes?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I look for a STL container class that provides immutability (once container is created, it is not allowed to do CRUD on the container. It is all read-only).

For sure, I can inherit STL container class and create an immutable version and then privatize all CRUD method and only keep constructor that take mutable container as input. Eg,

```
template<T>
public class ImmutableVector<T>(): public vecotr<T>()
{
    private void clear();

 ...
 }
```

But that seems A LOT OF WORK. My question is: are there STL immutable library out there in the world?

Comment: How will you get items into the container in the first place?

Comment: Point of order:  The "R" in CRUD stands for "Read" - you don't want to disable those methods.

Comment: @RichardCritten: Via the constructor of course.

Comment: You cannot use public inheritance and then privatize members. Your clients will just use the underlying base object. You need to *privately* inherit and then *publish* methods you want to expose.

Comment: That's what `const` is for.

Comment: @Martin Bonner. Good catch.  It should be CUD.

Comment: @n.m. I did a simple test. It works on clear() method. If client use the clear(), it failed at compile time in GCC.

Comment: *Your clients will just use the underlying base object*. Like this: `ImmutableVector<int> iv; iv.std::vector<int>::clear()`.

Answer (score 12):

You could use a `const` container, e.g. a `const std::vector<int>`. Very probably you'll use a mutable container at initialization and fill time, and later cast -perhaps using `const_cast`- it (or transmit it) as a `const` container, and more probably a `const` container *reference* (e.g. pass `const std::vector<int> &vi` as a formal to some function).

Comment: This works like a charm! I have been living in Java world for so long. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are no immutable containers in C++. The best way to make an immutable container is exactly what you are doing.

You would be better of making an `ImmutableVector<T>` class that takes in an initializer list to initialize a `std::vector` that's contained inside it. This way you can expose only const iterators and read functions instead of extending `std::vector`. If the STL implements more methods that are not read-only, they will be allowed to use until you manually disable them.

Example:

```cpp
template<typename T>
public class ImmutableVector<T>
{
    std::vector<T> vec;
public:
    typedef T value_type;
 ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. const on the object nails it! I tested it. It works. It can catch it at the compile time.

Comment: If const is doing the job, why someone should do so much work?

Comment: const on the object can be casted away using `const_cast<T>`. Also, STL containers can have performance limitations especially when it comes to cache locality. I don't suggest everyone make their own vector, but if you absolutely need it you can.